# Why in the browser does not show anything ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

I get from here : https://github.com/JellyBool/laravel-vue-pagination

Then, I clone it and I try on the my localhost

But, after it executed, in the browser does not show anything

I edit code on the `\resources\views\welcome.blade.php`like this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div id="app">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in items">
                        <a href="/item/@{{ item.id }}">
                            @{{ item.title }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li v-if="pagination.current_page > 1">
                            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous"
                               @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li v-for="page in pagesNumber"
                            v-bind:class="[ page == isActived ? 'active' : '']">
                            <a href="#"
                               @click.prevent="changePage(page)">@{{ page }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li v-if="pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page">
                            <a href="#" aria-label="Next"
                               @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.2.0/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                pagination: {
                    total: 0,
                    per_page: 7,
                    from: 1,
                    to: 0,
                    current_page: 1
                },
                offset: 4,// left and right padding from the pagination <span>,just change it to see effects
                items: []
            },
            ready: function () {
                this.fetchItems(this.pagination.current_page);
            },
            computed: {
                isActived: function () {
                    return this.pagination.current_page;
                },
                pagesNumber: function () {
                    if (!this.pagination.to) {
                        return [];
                    }
                    var from = this.pagination.current_page - this.offset;
                    if (from < 1) {
                        from = 1;
                    }
                    var to = from + (this.offset * 2);
                    if (to >= this.pagination.last_page) {
                        to = this.pagination.last_page;
                    }
                    var pagesArray = [];
                    while (from <= to) {
                        pagesArray.push(from);
                        from++;
                    }

                    return pagesArray;
                }
            },
            methods: {
                fetchItems: function (page) {
                    var data = {page: page};
                    this.$http.get('api/items', data).then(function (response) {
                        //look into the routes file and format your response
                        this.$set('items', response.data.data.data);
                        this.$set('pagination', response.data.pagination);
                    }, function (error) {
                        // handle error
                    });
                },
                changePage: function (page) {
                    this.pagination.current_page = page;
                    this.fetchItems(page);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

[image: js scripts]

Where are these files? You need to create js folder in current directory(inside of view folder), then get vue and vue-resource.min scripts from internet. Copy them and save in files. Or you can just include links to these scripts.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had change it. So, I use cdn vue. No error. But in the browser does not show anything

Comment: did you install all dependecies by 'composer install' command, then setup database? All necessary steps are listed in usage section in github link, you provided. Did you do them all correctly? You dont even need to include links, as I suggested.

Comment: Yes, I had install all dependecies and setup database. Seems I've done it all

Comment: if all steps are done correctly, it should work, if not - i dont know, maybe issue is on your localhost settings or something another.

Comment: Seems because I use vue.js version 2. While in tutorial uses the version under vue.js version 2. Maybe the syntax have to be adjusted to vue.js version 2

Comment: if you go to laravel-vue-pagination/public/js/vue-resource.min.js, you will see there vue-resource.min.js and vue.js files for version 1.0, which are included in welcome.blade.php. When you run a local serve, it generates another file for public (folder). As far as i know, vue still support previous versions.

Comment: Ok. I make new question. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176274/how-to-solve-error-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-create-property/undefined